# Error with Excel macro for logging into website

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I have a macro to open IE, login into a page, and pull a table. This is for our router, not a website. It's giving me the error "Object variable or With block variable not set." It highlights the "username" line in yellow in debugger.

This is the section of code from the website:

```
<form name="login_form" method="post" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="login" />
<div id="login_box">
    <div id="company_name">Copyright &copy; <span id="company_name_text"></span>. All rights reserved.</div>
    <div id="login_box_layout">
        <strong>Login</strong><br><br>
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" class="text_box" name="username" tabindex="1" autocapitalize="off"><br><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" class="text_box" name="password" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Login" tabindex="3" class="submit_action">
        <div class="smart_status" id="smart_status"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the macro:

```
Sub GetTable()   
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://192.168.1.1"
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.all.Item("username").Value = "admin123"
        .Document.all.Item("password").Value = "password123"
        .Document.forms(0).submit
    End With

    'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
    ieApp.Navigate "http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/MANGA/index.cgi?mode=config&option=utlog"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'get the table based on the table’s id
    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
    Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("device_log")

    'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
    If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
        Set clip = New DataObject
        clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
        clip.PutInClipboard
        Sheet1.Select
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
        Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the complete page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=582215646, affiliate-data=, app-argument=">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="connicon.cgi?type=favicon">
<title>Web Admin | Welcome</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#warning {
    margin:110px auto 10px;
    padding:30px;
    width:300px;
    background:#FCC;
    color:red;
    font-size:12px;
}
#login_box {
    position:relative;
    margin:80px auto 0;
    width:834px;
    height:434px;
    background:url("connicon.cgi?type=login_screen") no-repeat;
}
#login_box_layout {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto 0;
    padding:140px 0 0;
    width:250px;
}
.text_box {
    width:200px;
}
.smart_status {
    border:1px solid #FFCC56;
    color:#157015;
    font-weight:700;
    background:#FFFFB0;
    padding:5px 3px 3px 6px;
    margin:10px auto 0;
}
#company_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:385px;
    left:22px;
    border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    padding:5px;
    width:780px;
    background:#E9F1FC;
    font-size:9px;
}
div.notif_box {
    position:absolute;
    top:22px;
    left:22px;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    padding:10px;
    height:85px;
    width:770px;
    background: black;
    color:red;
    font:700 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

<!-- jQuery UI - Style Sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery-ui.css?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $" type="text/css" />
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery-ui-custom.css?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $" type="text/css" />
-->

<script src="../../MANGA/jquery.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI - Core -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.core.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.widget.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.button.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.mouse.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.position.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI - Dialog -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.draggable.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.resizable.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/jquery.ui.dialog.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>

<script src="../../MANGA/global.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../MANGA/validate_scripts.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../MANGA/menulib.js?$Name: Release-8_4_119_PATCH1 $"></script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <div id="warning">You must enable Javascript to access the Web Admin.</div>
</noscript>
<form name="login_form" method="post" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="login" />
<div id="login_box">
    <div id="company_name">Copyright &copy; <span id="company_name_text"></span>. All rights reserved.</div>
    <div id="login_box_layout">
        <strong>Login</strong><br><br>
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" class="text_box" name="username" tabindex="1" autocapitalize="off"><br><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" class="text_box" name="password" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Login" tabindex="3" class="submit_action">
        <div class="smart_status" id="smart_status"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var r0t1e=function(s){return s.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]/g,function(c){var v="m";return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)-13*(c>v?1:-1))});},r0tle=
["~!@#$%^&*()_+","cnggba","nenxavf","`{}|[]\;:<>?,./"];
$(function() {
        var l=window,I=l.r0t1e,I=I(l.oemid),l=0>$.inArray(I,l.r0tle);
        $("body").toggleClass(I,!l).css({"visibility":"visible"});
});
$(function() {
    var is_cookies_supported = (function() {
            var supported = false;
                n = "__cookies_test__";
                v = 100000000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000000);
            setCookie(n, v);
            if (getCookie(n) == v)
            {
                clearCookie(n);
                supported = true;
            }
            return supported;
        })(),
        w = window,
        o = $("body");

    // Ensure the Cookies is available, or we will block the login
    if (!is_cookies_supported)
    {
        o.empty().append(
            $("<div/>", { id: "warning" }).text("You must enable Cookies to access the Web Admin.")
        );
        return;
    }

    init_smart_status(status_message);

    if ($("body").hasClass("nenxavf"))
    {
        return nenxavf();
    }

    o.find("form[name=login_form]")
    .data("form_fields", [ "username", "password" ])
    .on("validate", function() {
        var form = $(this),
            is_valid = true;
        $.each(form.data("form_fields") || [], function(_, s) {
            var o = form.find("[name=\"" + s + "\"]");
            o.val(trim(o.val()));
            if (isempty(o.val()))
            {
                is_valid = false;
                return err(null, o);
            }
        })
        if (is_valid)
        {
            form.get(0).submit();
        }
    })
    .on("keydown", "input", function(e) { if (e.which == 13) { $(e.delegateTarget).triggerHandler("validate"); return false;} })
    .on("click", ".submit_action", function(e) { $(e.delegateTarget).triggerHandler("validate"); })
    .find("#login_box").append(w.has_notification? $("<div/>").addClass("notif_box").append(w.notification_msg): "").end()
    .find("#company_name_text").html(init_company_name).end()
    .show()
    .find("input:text:first").focus().end();
});
</script>


<style>
body.nenxavf .ui-widget {
    font:10pt Arial;
}
</style>
<script>
function nenxavf() {
    $("<form/>").append(
        $("<input/>", { type: "hidden", name: "func" }).val("login"),
        "The server requires a username and password<br><br>",
        $("<span/>").css({ display: "inline-block", width: "80px" }).text("Username: "),
        $("<input/>", { name: "username" }), "<br>",
        $("<span/>").css({ display: "inline-block", width: "80px" }).text("Password: "),
        $("<input/>", { name: "password", type: "password" }), "<br><br>"
    )
    .data("form_fields", [ "username", "password" ])
    .data("retries", 3)
    .on("validate", function() {
        var form = $(this),
            is_valid = true;
        $.each(form.data("form_fields") || [], function(_, s) {
            var o = form.find("[name=\"" + s + "\"]");
            o.val($.trim(o.val()));
            if (!o.val().length)
            {
                o.focus();
                is_valid = false;
            }
            return is_valid;
        })
        if (is_valid)
        {
            $.ajax("api.cgi", {
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                context: this
            })
            .then(function(json, status, jqXHR) {
                if (!(json && json["stat"] == "ok"))
                {
                    return $.Deferred()
                    .rejectWith(this, [ jqXHR, status, "Invalid Username or Password" ])
                    .promise();
                }
                return jqXHR;
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, status, msg) {
                var cls = "__err__",
                    form = $(this),
                    retry = +form.data("retries")-1;
                if (retry > 0)
                {
                    form
                    .data("retries", retry)
                    .find("."+cls).remove().end()
                    .append($("<div/>").css({ color: "red" }).addClass(cls).text(msg))
                    .find("[name=username]").val("").end()
                    .find("[name=password]").val("").end();
                }
                else
                {
                    form.dialog("close");
                }
            })
            .done(function() {
                goto_menu("mainpage");
            });
        }
    })
    .on("after_close", function() {
        $("body").empty().append(
            $("<div/>").css({ font: "bold 20pt Arial" }).text("Authorization Required"), "<br>",
            "This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested.", "<br><br>",
            "<hr>"
        );
    })
    .on("keyup", "input", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            $(e.delegateTarget).triggerHandler("validate");
        }
    })
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Authentication Required",
        close: function() {
            var me = $(this);
            me.triggerHandler("after_close");
        },
        buttons: [ {
            text: "Log In",
            click: function() {
            $(this).triggerHandler("validate");
            }
        }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                return $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        } ]
    })
}
</script>


<script>
var status_message = "",
    oemid = "PEPLINK",
    init_company_name = "Peplink",
    has_notification = false,
    notification_msg = "";
</script>
```

Comment: In my testing from your code sample, it worked for me. What is the real website URL? Also, if you are scraping from a live website, why is the form style display:none?

Comment: This is actually for our router. It's a Peplink One.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, in a different way, using "SendKeys" and pauses. This works fine.

```
   Dim ie As Object
    Dim dftname As String
    Dim dftpass As String

 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    dftname = "username"
    dftpass = "password"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/MANGA/index.cgi?mode=config&option=logout"
        Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

     End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    SendKeys dftname
    SendKeys "{Tab}"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    SendKeys dftpass
    SendKeys "{Enter}"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```